# I bought a car and suspect that it was sold to me with a tracking device installed I want to find it

Tags: gps

I **bought a car** and I suspect that it has a GPS tracking device installed in it. I have good reasons to suspect this. It has become a security risk.

The **car does not have any built in navigation** and **I recently changed my phone**.

I have looked in the tyre well, wheel arches, radiator area and everywhere inside. It is difficult to gain access under the rear bumper. Is there a known effective tool that can be used to detect this kind of device?

My understanding, having looked at some adverts, is that these devices are activated via motion. So I am not sure that I would easily locate it without a second person to assist.

Comment: Eyes are a good one, then look under the dash. Look for things that have recently appeared - new cf old etc wire joins that are not factory etc.

Comment: Some lenders require the use of such tracking devices as a condition of the loan.  These are especially prevalent at "buy-here-pay-here" and other lenders that cater to those with poor credit history.  You may want to review your loan document to be sure before doing anything.  If you purchased this outright then a tracking device would be inappropriate.  Why do you think there is one installed?

Comment: @jwh20 It is paid in full. This is a personal security situation.

Comment: So why do you believe there is a tracking device attached?

Comment: I'm asking over on a different stack if this might be a good fit there. I'm not seeing it getting answered by anyone here in any meaningful way on a time crunch kind of basis. This being New Years Eve (at the time of this comment), it might be tough getting anyone anywhere to answer very quickly.

Comment: If it was me, and I had a legitimate concern about this, I would trade the car. Drive to a somewhat far away used car dealer, ask them what they'll give you on trade in value, and find a car on their lot you are comfortable driving.  You'll be taking a loss and ending up with a less valuable vehicle, but you'll know it isn't being tracked.

Answer (score 2):

Almost always, the gps units (generally they are installed by loan companies for recovery purposes) are located under/behind the dash near the steering column area.

Remove the paneling if any and then look under the dash for wiring that looks abnormal. (bright colors that look a bit cheap. They are noticeably different then oem wiring ) You then follow these wires to find the device and remove it.

For the most part in reality gps units used in cars are simple devices and will have a BAT/RUN & ground connection to power it. They will be lazily tucked away somewhere close to where those connections are easily accessible.

In the spy world and movies I guess you would use a battery operated one tucked away somewhere simple under the car but its lifespan would be pretty short and reliability very low for the junk you see online.

Comment: Years ago,  the most popular aftermarket anti theft system used was LoJack, hidden away by installation specialists to prevent finding and deactivating it. Fast forward with Apple's Airtag  being slapped onto vehicles for smart thieves to track it back to owner's home then employ rfid technology to intercept remotes to enter, start and drive away a target vehicle. Any cellphone can be used to track Appletags but must have the code for each tag to track it. The unanswered question - what's being used if your vehicle has a tracking device in it.